# Shopping Cart Issue in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, shopping-cart

I am trying to create a shopping cart in CodeIgniter, I tried the method mentioned in the documentation and it works perfectly. But when I try to use it in the templetes it did not works. In the documentation, the products are hard coded but I am fetching the products from a database and inserting it using ajax.

**My Insert code JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
              var product_id=$(this).data("productid");
              var product_name=$(this).data("productname");
              var product_price=$(this).data("productprice");
               var quantity=$('#' + product_id).val();
               if(quantity !='' && quantity>0)
                   {
                       $.ajax({
                           url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Cart/insert_product",
                           method:"POST",
                           data:{
                               product_id:product_id,product_name:product_name,product_price:product_price,quantity:quantity
                           },
                           success:function(data)
                           {
                                alert("Product added into cart");
                          // alert("Product added into cart and product info is: ID:" + product_id +'\n\r name:' + product_name + '\n\r price:' + product_price + '\n\r quantity:' + quantity);
                             //  $('#' + product_id).val('');
                       }
                       });
                   }
               else
                   {
                       alert("Please enter quantity");
                   }
           });
        });
```

I test it using the alert to make sure that product is picking when I click "Add To Cart" Button.

**My Controller Insert_Product**

```
// my cart
    public function insert_product()
    {
          $data=array(
                'id'      => $_POST['product_id'],
                'qty'     => $_POST['quantity'],
                'price'   => $_POST['product_price'],
                'name'    => $_POST['product_name']
        );
        // Inesrting Items into Cart
            $this->cart->insert($data);
    }
```

When I click on "Add To Cart" Button it shows me the success message, but I am pretty sure that the product is not inserting into the cart...

**Place Where I am trying to access the product.**

```
 <!-- cart items -->
                      <div class="nav-cart-items">
                        <?php $i = 1; 
                          if(!$this->cart->contents()){echo "no items found in cart";}
                          foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items): 
                         var_dump($items);
                          if(empty($items)){echo "cart is empty";}else{ echo "<h1>cart has data</h1>";?>
                        <div class="nav-cart-item clearfix">
                         <h4>Cart Details</h4>
                          <div class="nav-cart-img">

                            <a href="#">
                              <img src="cart_small_1.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="nav-cart-title">
                            <a href="#">
                              <?php echo $items['name'];?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="nav-cart-price">
                              <span><?php echo $items['qty'];?> x</span>
                              <span><?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['price']);?></span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="nav-cart-remove">
                            <a href="#"><i class="ui-close"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php $i++; ?>
                    <?php } endforeach;?>
                      </div> <!-- end cart items -->
```

I am echoing the message `"no items found in cart"` if there are no items in the cart, and it shows me that. I also try this code

```
<?php
ob_start();
   var_dump($this->cart->contents());
   $result = ob_get_contents();
?>
```

to test the contents and it shows me the  **output** :

```
F:\xampp\htdocs\cart\application\views\single_item.php:3:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

As for I think that I am doing something wrong, but don't know where...
Please also suggest a cart solution in CodeIgniter, as in the documentation the Cart library is depreciated.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: print_r($data); after the array in insert_product()... does the array have data when you add an item via ajax? (should be able to see this in your network preview tab)

Comment: i am not seeing any data information regarding product in network tab except
`Request URL:http://localhost/cart/product/5
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 08 Mar 2018 03:55:30 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100`

Comment: Open dev tools (chrome) > network tab. Submit the ajax request by adding an item to cart, you should see at the end of the list an item by the name of `insert_product`. Click that, then more tabs should show up. One will have response data, click that, you should see your array. This is ajax debugging 101.

Comment: data is now showing but the url seems incorrect... its showing like.

`Request URL:http://localhost/cart/product/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url();?%3ECart/insert_product
`

Comment: Your JavaScript wouldn't happen to be in a separate document would it? e.g. something.js

Comment: yes, it is in custom.js

Comment: you don't see a problem with running (or rather not running) php scripts in js? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP scripts, namely: `<?php echo base_url();?>` will not execute in `.js` files. Hence how in the comments your url is showing up in dev tools verbatim.

You could move the contents of the js file to your header template so it resides in a view. Or you could just define the `base_url()` yourself in js as a var (`var base_url = 'http://somesite.com/';`) and use it like `base_url` or do something like:

`url:"/cart/insert_product"` assuming that `cart` is not in a subdir of `controllers`

Comment: can you please guide me through the image process.. i am trying to show image with item, but it is not working.

Comment: link me the question on stack and ill take a look. (if you haven't made a question make a new one)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you used $data in Controller.
If i am not wrong then you are sending values separately , not in " $data multiassociative array "

```
$data=array(
              array(
                'id'      => $_POST['product_id'],
                'qty'     => $_POST['quantity'],
                'price'   => $_POST['product_price'],
                'name'    => $_POST['product_name'])
        );
```

try to remove $data=array() and used following code:

```
 $id = $this->input->post('product_id');
        $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
       $product_price = $this->input->post('product_price');
        $product_name = $this->input->post('product_name');
```

Comment: refer this question for more detail -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461369/how-does-codeigniter-receive-the-ajax-post-data-in-controller

Comment: There is functionally no difference between using the input class to get post vars and using the post vars themselves...

Answer (score 0):

I usually get the post data and insert into the table in this way:

```
 $productId = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('product_id'));
 $quantity = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('quantity'));
 $productPrice = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('product_price'));
 $productName = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('product_name'));


    $data = array(
       "id" => $productId,
       "qty" => $quantity,
       "price" => $productPrice,
       "name" => $productName
    );

    $this->cart->insert($data);
```