# jquery ajax not posting any data on codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

hy please help me i working on ajax but when i var_dump the data it seem empty

> object(stdClass)#20 (0) { }

```
$.ajax({
            url: base_url+"process_redeem_check",
            data: $("#formId").serializeArray(),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
```

thats is my javascript code

```
public function process_redeem_check()
{
    $input = (object) $this->input->post();
    $check = $this->gemstone_model->redeem_check($input);
    if ($check->success === TRUE) {
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>true));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>false));
    }

}
```

that my controller please help me i done searching all day

Comment: Can you also show us your form?

Comment: Are you sure the data is send to `process_redeem_check()`? Read [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39463276/5474196) or example [here](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-jquery-ajax-post/)

Comment: You dont need the base url in your url. Is "process_redeem_check" the name of your controller AND method? You are not directing your url to a controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `$this->input->post()` initialize the form helper. You could do that by default in config folder's `autoload.php.`

include form in the the array.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

and use `.serialize()` instead of `serializeArray()`

```
$.ajax({
            url: base_url+"process_redeem_check",
            data: $("#formId").serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
```

And then check you datas your are getting or not

```
public function process_redeem_check()
{
    $input = $this->input->post();
    print_r($input);exit;


}
```

Comment: I can be wrong here, but base_url+"process_redeem_check" doesnt send the data to any controller, just a method. Shouldn't he address the url like this: "controller/method"

Comment: Yes, it should be url: base_url+"controller/process_redeem_check",

Comment: In addition, the base_url is not needed. Codeigniter knows where it is being addressed to. Just use url: "controller/method"